# Select into table from list of CSV

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

A python list of CSV files must be loaded into Access from pyodbc. I don't understand how to write the SQL string to accommodate a variable in place of explicitly defining the INTO TABLE & the FROM CSV file.

A fully functional SQL statement for a single CSV looks like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [TableName] FROM 
[text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);" + 
"Database=C:\Path\To\Folder].first.csv;"
```

Can this statement be modified to accommodate a variable representing the CSV to import (ie, both the INTO [TableName] and the FROM database)?

I understand it's some form similar to this:

```
strSQL ="SELECT * INTO ? FROM Database=?",[csv_string, csv]
```

but the complex FROM statement that references a database has me scratching my head.

```
# DATABASE CONNECTION
access_path = "C:\Path\To\Access\\DB.mdb"
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver 
(*.mdb,*.accdb)}};DBQ={};".format(access_path))

for csv in csv_list:

    # RUN QUERY
    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [TableName] FROM 
    [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);" + 
    "Database=C:\Path\To\Folder].first.csv;"    

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(strSQL)
    con.commit()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `.format()` like you do above?

You could do the following:

```py
table = "TableName"
database = "C:\Path\To\Folder"

strSQL = """
SELECT * INTO [{}] FROM
[text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);
{}].first.csv;
""".format(table, database)
```

Or you could use the following format:

```py
strSQL = f"SELECT * INTO [{table}] FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);{database}].first.csv;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer selected, here is the final formatting that works correctly:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [{}] FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);".format(csv_str) + \
          "Database=C:\PathToFolder].{};".format(csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could use Python to load CSV files into Access, but why go through all the trouble.  just use Access to import the CSv files (don't create a lot of unnecessary work for yourself).

Import CSV Files Into Separate Tables:

```
Function DoImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the CSV files
 strPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"

 ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
 ' the data are to be imported

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()
 Loop

End Function
```

OR...

Import CSV Files Into ONE Table:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String, strBrowseMsg As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        strBrowseMsg = "Select the folder that contains the CSV files:"

        strPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\LinkedIn\Import all CSV Files into Different Access Tables\"

        If strPath = "" Then
              MsgBox "No folder was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
              Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.csv")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & "\" & strFile

        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop
End Sub
```